# Extract data frames from list to global environment

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes in a list. Let’s say, for making it short and easy, I have iris and mtcars:

```
my_list <- list (mydf1=iris, mydf2=mtcars)
```

Is there any simple way to extract all dataframes to global environment no matter how many of them are in the list?.

From this example, After extracting I must have two data frames: mydf1 and mydf2

Comment: Why do you want to flood global environment of *many* data frames and not use **one** list?

Comment: Each dataframe has a different treatment as they are different kinds of data