# Convert a list with dataframes into multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list with multiple data frames (these were split by group). Any leads on how to convert this list into multiple dataframes? (Ideally would want to convert them to multiple matrices). Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the list2env function? It's usually better to store related dataframes in a list though.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347629/extract-data-frames-from-list-to-global-environment